# TENSORFLOW worker out of memory in google bigquery

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

I trained an `AUTOML_REGRESSOR` model in google bigquery.
When I try to predict my data, about 30 million rows, I get the error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Resources exceeded during query execution: TENSORFLOW worker out of memory. 
This model used too much memory when loaded into RAM to run predictions.
This model may be too complex to run efficiently inside of BigQuery.
```

I tried to batch up the prediction and just predict 10K rows per batch, but the error is the same.
Any ideas how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have not played with AUTOML_REGRESSOR yet, but I know that regression models are sensitive to the input column type. Like one of the columns contains unique names that are very hard to generalize to make a prediction.

You may try to limit your input to numeric columns only as a work around.